# Property_exists Returns false?

Tags: php

I am trying to create objects from sql rows via active record pattern and on debugging the array is showing via print_r and I have cross-checked many times for the column name to match variable names and other stuff but to no avail .
Here is the code gist.

```
class  CustOrder{

    public $CustomerId;
    public $OrderId;
    public $Dish;
    public $Dish1;
    public $Dish2;
    public $Dish3;
    public $Dish4;
    public $Dish5;
    public $Dish6;
    public $Dish7;
    public $Dish8;
    public $Dish9;
    public $Dish10;
    public $Dish11; 

    public function __construct($args=[]){
        $this->CustomerId = $args['CustomerId'] ?? '';
        $this->OrderId = $args['OrderId'] ?? '';
        $this->Dish = $args['Dish'] ?? '';
        $this->Dish1 = $args['Dish1'] ?? '';
        $this->Dish2 = $args['Dish2'] ?? '';
        $this->Dish3 = $args['Dish3'] ?? '';
        $this->Dish4 = $args['Dish4'] ?? '';
        $this->Dish5 = $args['Dish5'] ?? '';
        $this->Dish6 = $args['Dish6'] ?? '';
        $this->Dish7 = $args['Dish7'] ?? '';
        $this->Dish8 = $args['Dish8'] ?? '';
        $this->Dish9 = $args['Dis9'] ?? '';
        $this->Dish10 = $args['Dish10'] ?? '';
        $this->Dish11 = $args['Dish11'] ?? '';

    }

    static  protected $database;

    static public function set_database($database){
        self::$database = $database;    
    }

    static public function get_all_orders(){
        $sql = "Select *  from orderz";
        return self::find_by_sql($sql);
    }

    static public function find_by_sql($sql){
        $result = self::$database->query($sql);
        if(!$result){
            exit("database query failed");
        }
        $object_array=[];
        while($record = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $object_array[]=self::instantiate($record);

        }
        $result->free();
        return $object_array;

        //return $result;
    }

    static protected function instantiate($record){

        $object = new CustOrder;
            //automatic assignment faster and reusable 
        foreach($record as $property => $value){
            if(property_exists($object,$property)){
                $object->$property  = $value;
                echo "hello";
            }else{
                    //echo print_r($record[0]);
            }
        }
        return $object;
    }
}
```

The set_database call is made via PDO and the  method i am talking about is instantiate.

Answer (score 0):

Use It Like This:- 
`if ('CustomerId' in $object)`  OR
Check for everything:-

```
echo "<pre>";print_r($object);
echo "<pre>";print_r($property);
if(property_exists($object,$property)){

            $object->$property  = $value;



            echo "hello";
        }else{
            //echo print_r($record[0]);
        }
```